# Regex for Detecting Complex Attack Strings on Web Sites

Tags: regex, nginx, fail2ban

I am no genius with Regex but wondered if it is possible to write some kind of Regex pattern to detect these complex attack strings which I am sure many people have seen in their web server logs.

These strings change so frequently and I'm sure someone skilled in Regex could find a way to detect these and one could use this regex in a custom Fail2Ban filter.

Here's just a few samples of some of the Attack strings.

```
\x03\x00\x00)$\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x03\x00\x00)$\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x16\x03\x01\x01\x22\x01\x00\x01\x1E\x03\x03\xB2\xF2\x5CF\x0C\xD8eb\x92m\x19\xBB\x81\xCE\x90\x9C\xC5\x90r+\x98@\xC00\x1AS4\xF3\xB9\x86\xF6\xC2\x00\x00\x88\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0
Gh0st\xAD\x00\x00\x00\xE0\x00\x00\x00x\x9CKS``\x98\xC3\xC0\xC0\xC0\x06\xC4\x8C@\xBCQ\x96\x81\x81\x09H\x07\xA7\x16\x95e&\xA7*\x04$&g+\x182\x94\xF6\xB000\xAC\xA8rc\x00\x01\x11\xA0\x82\x1F\x5C`&\x83\xC7K7\x86\x19\xE5n\x0C9\x95n\x0C;\x84\x0F3\xAC\xE8sch\xA8^\xCF4'J\x97\xA9\x82\xE30\xC3\x91h]&\x90\xF8\xCE\x97S\xCBA4L?2=\xE1\xC4\x92\x86\x0B@\xF5`\x0CT\x1F\xAE\xAF]
\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03\xCF#vw\x1Ew\x8A(7~R\x9F\xEF\xFFo\x1D\xDC\x97\x8A\xBC\xD4\x82\x1C\x81\x06\xC1\x93@mv\xF5\x15\x00\x00\xD8\x00\x05\x00\x04\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x16\x003\x009\x00:\x00\x18\x005\x00
\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03\xE0^\xF6\x15\x9A\xA1\xD8\x02\x9A\xF2\x0B\x07\x89\xC7o\x83\xBE\xF4e\xC0\xC4\x0B\xA4\xA7_X\xFAItf\xA9\x00\x00\x00\xD8\x00\x05\x00\x04\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x16\x003\x009\x00:\x00\x18\x005\x00
\x16\x03\x01\x00\x8B\x01\x00\x00\x87\x03\x03\x22\xFCk\x07L\x07=\x22\xE9\x97\x82\xD9qu\x8C \x06\xE0\x10\x1E\x8A\xC5\xB1\xC7\xF2>6x
%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4
%D0%A7%D0%B0%D0%B4%20%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8
```

**Update: The requests come in looking like this. No use of GET, HEAD or POST.**

```
164.52.7.132 - - [07/Sep/2017:11:07:29 +0200] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\x22\x01\x00\x01\x1E\x03\x03\xB2\xF2\x5CF\x0C\xD8eb\x92m\x19\xBB\x81\xCE\x90\x9C\xC5\x90r+\x98@\xC00\x1AS4\xF3\xB9\x86\xF6\xC2\x00\x00\x88\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 166 "-" "-"
```

Comment: These come up as method names or request body or how?

Comment: They come in looking like this `164.52.7.132 - - [07/Sep/2017:11:07:29 +0200] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\x22\x01\x00\x01\x1E\x03\x03\xB2\xF2\x5CF\x0C\xD8eb\x92m\x19\xBB\x81\xCE\x90\x9C\xC5\x90r+\x98@\xC00\x1AS4\xF3\xB9\x86\xF6\xC2\x00\x00\x88\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 166 "-" "-"`

Comment: May be something like this? `^(?:(?:\w+)?\\x[^\\\n]+)+|(?:%[A-F0-9]{2})+$`  https://regex101.com/r/LcEOF3/1

Comment: Why not just restrict the methods 
`add_header Allow "GET, POST, HEAD" always;
if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD)$ ) {
 return 405;
}`

Comment: Thanks Tarun, I thought about that as a solution. I will review some more logs to see if any of these come in using GET HEAD or POST. 

Thanks also Gurman, I will try out that Regex on a Fail2ban filter and see how it works.

Comment: One user on one of my projects suggested this regex `failregex = ^<HOST> .* ".*\\x.*" .*$`

Answer (score 9):

There is a solution to ban complex attack strings at the fail2ban level and hence block the ip address for a predetermined time period.

It was discussed in this thread below:

https://github.com/mariusv/nginx-badbot-blocker/issues/157

**jail.local**

```
[nginx-x00]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = nginx-x00
logpath  = /var/log/nginx/access.log
bantime  = 86400
findtime = 86400
maxretry = 2
```

**filter.d/nginx-x00.conf**

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> .* ".*\\x.*" .*$
ignoreregex =
```